# Pull out from first value of List<Pair<String,String>> and set on TextView

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I have pass from my MainFragment to my adapter list:

```
 viewModelAppe.getResponseLiveDataCombinedResult().observe(getActivity(),
                combinedResult -> mainAdapter.setProjectList(combinedResult.getArtistsWithPhoto()
                )) ;
```

my method in adaper:

```
private List<Pair<String,String>> localList  = Collections.emptyList();
public void setProjectList (final List<Pair<String,String>> list ){
    if (list != null){

        localList = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else {
        Log.v("LOGer","isssue in adapter");
    }
}
```

- my class CombinedResult

  public class CombinedResult {

  ```
  List<Pair<String,String>> perfectMapNameAndFoto;
  private final RootiTune ituneResult;
  private final RootLastFm lastFmResult;

  public CombinedResult(RootiTune ituneResult, RootLastFm lastFmResult) {
      this.ituneResult = ituneResult;
      this.lastFmResult = lastFmResult;
  }


  public List<Pair<String,String>> getArtistsWithPhoto ()
  {
      perfectMapNameAndFoto = new ArrayList<>() ;


      if (ituneResult.getListSongs() != null){
          for (ResultiTune item : ituneResult.getListSongs() ){

              perfectMapNameAndFoto.add(new Pair <String,String> (item.getArtistName(),item.getArtworkUrl100() ));
          }
      }
      if(lastFmResult.getResults().getArtistmatches().getListOfLatsFmArtists() != null) {
          for (ArtistLastFm item : lastFmResult.getResults().getArtistmatches().getListOfLatsFmArtists())
              perfectMapNameAndFoto.add(new Pair<String, String>(item.getName(), item.getUrl()));
      }


      return perfectMapNameAndFoto;

  }
  ```

  }

and method:

```
    @BindingAdapter("setName")
    public static void setName (@NonNull TextView textView, Pair <String,String> value, CombinedResult name){

        name.getArtistsWithPhoto();
        List<Pair<String, String>> valuePair = name.getArtistsWithPhoto();
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(valuePair));

}
```

**Question:**

my problem is that I dont know how to pull out data from first String

```
 List<Pair<String,String>
```

first String contain name that I want put in my textView at item_list in recyclerView, second is foto that in this case is irrelevant.

Comment: According to documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair, use first and second properties to get parts of `Pair`. In your case to set artist name use `textView.setText(valuePair.first);`

Comment: How do you call `BindingAdapter` from layout? Can you show your requirement?

Comment: thanks for response ! I fix my issue by converting my List<Pair<String,String> to List<Pair<String> using Strem: List<String> localArtistNameList = Stream.of(List).map(p -> p.first).collect(Collectors.toList());